# «Знать не знал» — фразеологизм или нет?

Tags: фразеология, классификация

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли словосочетание ***знать не знал*** назвать фразеологизмом?
Некоторые источники утверждают, что это фразеологизм.

Answer (score 4):

[**Знать не знаю**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-22968.htm#%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC_%D0%9D%D0%95_%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%AE_(%D0%9D%D0%95_%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%95%D0%A8%D0%AC_%D0%98_%D0%A2._%D0%94.)__%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (знать не знаешь, знать не знали, знать не знал...) — о полной неосведомленности в чем-либо; о нежелании признать что-либо.

Репертуар русскаго и пантеон всѣх европейских театров ([**1842**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=wsI9AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PA3&lpg=RA4-PA3&dq=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8A%20(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8A)%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E,%20%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E!&source=bl&ots=_hyqKMnboO&sig=ACfU3U1lyq7I7daV2Kam-XCeweOyyDMxuQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8p8-89LvqAhVfwcQBHR8ZB3kQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8A%20(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8A)%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E!&f=false)):
Иванъ (*прикинувшись простачкомъ*).
Помилуйте, батюшка баринъ! **Знать не знаю**, вѣдать не вѣдаю!

В толковом словаре [**Даля**](http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=10785) (‎1863—1866):
Знать не знаю — а дело мое! **Знать не знаешь**, так и вины нет, только не признавайся.

> И вот — по тундре мы, как сиротиночки, —
> Не по дороге всё, а по тропиночке.
> Куда мы шли — в Москву или в Монголию, —
> **Он знать не знал**, паскуда, я — тем более.
> В. Высоцкий (**1962**)

Выражение (в разных формах) используется в языке более полутора веков.
Думаю, что его можно квалифицировать как устойчивое словосочетание.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вопрос мне показался интересным, но вот **ответить на него сложно.** В области фразеологии лично мне не хватает **точности и определенности**, и именно эти проблемы я вижу в заданной теме. Поэтому  надеюсь, что будут и другие ответы.
2. У Риммы приводится интересный и познавательный материал **о самом фразеологизме,** но не о его **классификации**, а вот вопрос был именно об этом.
3. **Можно ли назвать сочетание фразеологизмом?** Чтобы ответить, надо знать следующее.

Прежде всего, какой **основной признак** у фразеологизма? Могу предположить, что это воспроизводимость в речи, но не уверена.

Также надо знать, как это понятие **соотносится с похожими названиями**: целостное (цельное) выражение, устойчивое выражение (словосочетание).  Как грамотно использовать все эти названия: к примеру, это выражение или словосочетание?
И если ли  похожие понятия **нефразеологического характера**, где грань между ними?

4. Рассмотрим это конкретное выражение: ***знать не знал;  знать не знаю***.

Характерным признаком здесь является **повтор**, но что это за повтор?

Существуют чисто языковые повторы, например: ***сиди не сиди, ждет не дождется, сказал так сказал*.** Это глагольные, а есть еще именные: ***чином чином, дурак дураком**.*

Это что, тоже фразеологизмы? Тогда надо хотя бы в общих чертах определять их **разновидность и структуру**. Например, что лежит в основе заданного выражения – словосочетание или предложение?

5. И **про источники** интересный вопрос. Получается, что только некоторые считают «знать не знаю» фразеологизмом,  другие же иначе называют, **а вот как?**

Таким образом, вместо ответа получается сборник вопросов. С другой стороны, правильно спросить – это уже наполовину ответить, так что не хватает второй половины.